# emacs flycheck syntax checher for cpp file

Tags: c++, emacs, flycheck

I am using Emacs 24.3.1 to edit a `.cpp` file and when I activate `M-x flycheck-mode`, it shows the state being `(C++/l FlyC- Abbrev)`, where `FlyC-` means it did not find a suitable syntax checker.

I can't see anything looking like a C++ checher in the list I get from `flycheck-select-checker`:

```
Possible completions are:
bash    coffee-coffeelint   css-csslint
emacs-lisp  emacs-lisp-checkdoc     go-build
go-gofmt    go-test     haml
html-tidy   javascript-jshint   json-jsonlint
lua     perl    php
php-phpcs   python-flake8   python-pyflakes
python-pylint   rst     ruby
rust-rustc  sass    scss
sh  tex-chktex  tex-lacheck
xml-xmlstarlet  zsh
```

Any ideas what might be missing?

Comment: Any C++ checker worth its salt is basically a compiler. So why not just use that.

Comment: For reference: See https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck/issues/233 for  the upstream issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have both `c/c++-clang` and `c/c++-cppcheck` when I run `flycheck-select-checker`. Perhaps you're using an out of date flycheck?

Comment: I redid a `M-x package-install` + `flycheck` and it did the whole `Contacting host marmalade, ..., compiling, ... Done (Total of 2 files compiled, 1 skipped)` so I am assuming the installation succeeds, but still, no sign of c++-clang or c++-cppcheck anywhere.

Comment: Try [MELPA](http://melpa.milkbox.net/), it's more recent (and more unstable, generally than Marmalade).

Comment: After installing an up-to-date version of flycheck, and pointing the clang and cppcheck binaries to my $PATH, it now works.